# jQuizMe with strange "undefined" word

Tags: javascript, html

jQuizMe is making Quiz as multichoice

There is 2 wrong answer her one of them when I choose it (I'm going home) showing it with "undefined" word and I dont want this word to show, her is the code:

```
    <script language="javascript">

    var quiz4 = [
        {
        "ques":"    How are you?", 
        "ans":"I'm fine ", 
        "ansSel":["Thank you", "I'm going home"],
        "feeds":[""], "wrongFeed":"" , "rightFeed":" "
        }


    ]; 
     var options = { "quizType":"multiplyChoiceOl", "showWrongAns":true ,"Great good job" :'<font color=green>Right Answer</font>',"wrong":"Wrong answer, try again","empty":"<font color=red>please choose your answer</font>","title":' ', "finished_msg":""}  ;
    $( "#quiz_div" ).jQuizMe( quiz4, options);
</script>
```

Any help with that?

Comment: Although I can try to guess what you're asking, it's still not clear.  Try to split your text into sentences - it really helps readability.

Comment: Ok as u can at the code there is 3 answers 2 of them is wrong. when I choose "Thank you" its work fine with no "undefined" word, but when I choose the sec. choise and its wrong too "I'm going home" the word "undefined" appear! that is the problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry  but I don't understand your question.
Could you please rephrase it.

Anyhow, it seems that the problem is that you're using a modified version of jQuizMe.
How do I know?
jQuizMe displays an error message instead of the quiz, if any of the elements of the quiz input is unknown.

I corrected your input to allow the quiz to run, but that's all I can do until you rephrase the question and provide the customize script.

Source:

```
$(function () {
  var quiz4 = [{
      "ques": "    How are you?",
      "ans": "I'm fine ",
      "ansSel": ["Thank you", "I'm going home"] //,
      //"feeds":[""], "wrongFeed":"" , "rightFeed":" " // unknown keys
  }];
  var options = {
      "quizType": "multipleChoiceOl", // this was misspelled
      "showWrongAns": true,
      "Great good job": '<font color=green>Right Answer</font>',
      "wrong": "Wrong answer, try again",
      "empty": "<font color=red>please choose your answer</font>",
      "title": ' ',
      "finished_msg": ""
  };
  $("#quiz_div").jQuizMe(quiz4, options);
});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/eAFkr/